# Required java.lang.String[] found java.lang.String

Tags: java

Добрый день, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Создал массив и инициализировал в нем элементы. Затем решил использовать массив в `switch`. Массив у меня типа `String`. В блоке `switch` возникает ошибка:

> Required java.lang.String[] found java.lang.String

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся или что еще нужно сделать? И вообще, можно ли использовать `String` массив в `switch`?

```
 package com.company;


 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Person Alex = new Person();
    Alex.Speak(" Alex");
    System.out.println("What kind of job I have to do today?");
    String kindofjob = s.nextLine();

    String[] joboffer = {
            "carry box",
            "eat smth",
            "say my name"
    };

    switch (joboffer) {
        case "carry box":
            Alex.Work(kindofjob);
            break;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Нет, массивы нельзя использовать как параметр switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете использовать массив как параметр `switch`. Если вы хотите пройти по всем элементам массива и обработать совпадения, используйте цикл и внутри него проверяйте. Например Ваш `switch` можно было бы заменить таким циклом

```
for(String str: joboffer){
    switch (str) {
            case "carry box":
                Alex.Work(kindofjob);
                break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

так нельзя писать. в свитч можно передать стринг, но не его массив. какую вы реакцию ожидаете на case "carry box"? да, один из элементов массива совпадает по содержанию со строкой, но не сам массив как объект. хотите искать элементы в массиве - придется гонять цикл. но лучше используйте HashSet, его метод contains очень быстро определит , есть ли в данной коллекции такая строка.

```
Set <String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("carry box");
set.add("eat smth");
set.add("say my name");

boolean contains = set.contains("carry box");
```

примерно так. в переменной boolean contains будет результат проверки на наличие элемента. мало того, создавая коллекцию типа Set, вы можете помимо HashSet выбрать  LinkedHashSet, который сохранит тот порядок элементов, в котором вы их хаписываете, либо TreeSet, который автоматически отсортирует. К тому же в коллекциях еще много всяких плюшек по сравнению с массивами.